# app crash as soon as it starts on Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

In Xcode 11, My app runs fine for the first time but once it is killed or crashed, it can not be opened, it keep crashing with below error log

crash log

````
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1866b80a4 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x186884ac8 +[NSException raise:format:] + 107
3   UIFoundation                    0x189f1eed0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 407
4   UIFoundation                    0x189ebb6b8 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 315
5   Foundation                      0x186cb7630 -[NSLayoutConstraint initWithCoder:] + 227
6   UIFoundation                    0x189f1f010 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
7   UIFoundation                    0x189ebb6b8 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 315
8   UIKitCore                       0x18a626568 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 171
9   UIFoundation                    0x189f1f010 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 727
10  UIFoundation                    0x189f1f244 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1291
11  UIFoundation                    0x189ebb6b8 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 315
12  UIKitCore                       0x18a6215b4 -[NSCoder+ 6874548 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 487
13  UIKitCore                       0x18a6241a4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1111
14  UIKitCore                       0x18a36e8b0 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 363
15  UIKitCore                       0x18a36f2ec -[UIViewController loadView] + 175
16  UIKitCore                       0x18a36f5a4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 171
17  UIKitCore                       0x18a2e1f70 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 167
18  UIKitCore                       0x18a2e227c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 175
19  UIKitCore                       0x18a2e30b0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1135
20  UIKitCore                       0x18a2e43f4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 163
21  UIKitCore                       0x18a2c81c8 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
22  UIKitCore                       0x18adf6d3c -[UIView+ 15088956 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2139
23  QuartzCore                      0x18d2f012c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 283
24  QuartzCore                      0x18d2f495c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1399132 (CA::Transaction*) + 479
25  QuartzCore                      0x18d300350 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1446736 (CA::Transaction*) + 135
26  QuartzCore                      0x18d248edc CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 696028 (CA::Transaction*, double) + 295
27  QuartzCore                      0x18d272e44 CA::Transaction::commit+ 867908 () + 675
28  UIKitCore                       0x18a988f98 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 79
29  CoreFoundation                  0x18690cec4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 19
30  CoreFoundation                  0x18690c664 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 263
31  CoreFoundation                  0x1869078e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1099
32  CoreFoundation                  0x18690716c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 463
33  GraphicsServices                0x19073f328 GSEventRunModal + 103
34  UIKitCore                       0x18a971d0c UIApplicationMain + 1935
35  -------------                   0x104ea06c0 0x104e94000 + 50880
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x186792424 start + 3```
````

Comment: Try with an `exception breakpoint`, maybe you can narrow down your issue to a specific place in your code.

Comment: Having the same issue. Unfortunately, it only crashes without the debugger attached :/

Comment: For me when I ran it on Simulator, it showed the error. Had one framework missing from Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content section under general Tab for target.

Comment: @Kanika have you found out where it came from? I have the same issue, it seems it can't deserialize storyboards, but I can't understand why!

Comment: It happen for me when I had outlet reference in the storyboard and not in the view controller to link it with. When i created a IBOutlet in the view controller and liked it in the storyboard, error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because of a `UITextView` in a storyboard and a critical issue in Xcode 11.2 fixed in Xcode 11.2.1 GM : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_1_gm_seed_release_notes/

> This update fixes a critical issue that could cause apps using UITextView to crash when run on previous versions of iOS, iPadOS, or tvOS. Please see the release notes.